# Creating a method inside a thread using ... extend Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, class, netbeans, thread-safety

I was wondering if the name of the method for a thread always has to be run().

Example:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    run(){
    ... doing something
    }
}
```

compared to:

```
public MyThread extends Thread{
    sendEmail(String name){
    ... do something
    }
}
```

when calling the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new MyThread();
    t1.start();
}
```

I was wondering if `run()` has to be explicitly defined in the thread class or not. Will they work the same or how do I put a method inside a `run()` that has to be public as its getting called.

Comment: How would it know about the `sendEmail` method and how would it know what parameter value to supply?

Comment: In general you shouldn't `extend Thread`, but instead `implement Runnable` and use `new Thread(new YourRunnable())` (or better yet, pass the instance of `YourRunnable` to an executor service).

Answer (score 1):

The **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), says:

> There are two ways to create a new thread of execution. One is to declare a class to be a subclass of `Thread`. This subclass should **override the `run` method** of class `Thread`.
>
> [...]
>
> The other way to create a thread is to declare a class that implements the `Runnable` interface. That class then **implements the `run` method**.

In either case, you **must implement a no-arg method named `run`**.

If you prefer your method to be named something else, just call the method from the `run` method.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendEmail("Hello World");
    }
    private void sendEmail(String name) {
        ... do something
    }
}
```

Of course, you would normally want `name` to come from outside, so:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private final String name;
    public MyThread(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendEmail();
    }
    private void sendEmail() {
        ... do something here, using this.name
    }
}
```